# Access to Notes client Java plug-ins in XPiNC

Tags: xpages, xpinc

The Notes client Eclipse API has a number of interesting features:

- you can register a ISelectionListener to see what is selected in other parts of the application without touching the other part
- you can talk to the Eclipse EventAdmin (one level lower than the property broker)
- use any other plug-in

My primary interest would be to use the result ISelectionListener in an XPiNC app (or the eventAdmin - I can write a plug-in that send the stuff I'm interested in to the EventAdmin)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karsten Lehmann gave a Lotusphere session about this: http://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/17.01.2011061656KLE886.htm

Answer (score 1):

Teresa did a video on this, but it seems to have disappeared.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPage_Components_in_Notes_851_Videos.htm

Poke me on Monday and I will try get the wiki fixed. As I understand it you create a plugin which you can trigger via a Wire.

Comment: Wires are notoriously unreliable. I'd rather find a way via the API